# Need to change dropdown menu container alignment

Tags: html, css

I have to duplicate the header and footer of a site for use in hosted services but there's just one thing that I just can't figure out. It has to do with the dropdown link containers at the header.

If you look at their menu, the dropdown box is centered below the parent link.  My dropdown container is aligned left, meaning that the left edge of my dropdown link container starts at the left edge of the parent link.

My page: https://schw.im/wix1/index.html

My menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWV1h.jpg

Original page: https://thetechguysnc.wixsite.com/website

Their menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1aiK.jpg

How can I center the containers below the parent link?

```css
.nondropbtn a:hover {
  color: #BBB09E;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: #FF01FF;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: RalewayBold, sans-serif;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #597EA5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: RalewayBold, sans-serif;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  transition: color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: #bbb0a5;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1 class="htitle">Your Mountain Dreams</h1>
  <div id="header-content">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="nondropbtn"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="nondropbtn"><a href="#">About</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="nondropbtn"><a href="#">News</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropbtn">Search MLS</div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Featured Listings</a>
        <a href="#">Quick Search</a>
        <a href="#">Basic Search</a>
        <a href="#">Advanced Search</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="nondropbtn"><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropbtn">Area Info</div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Area Schools</a>
        <a href="#">Area Entertainment</a>
        <a href="#">Professional Contacts</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="nondropbtn"><a href="#">Testimonials</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="nondropbtn"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would you post your code here...

Comment: Posted the relevant bits.

Comment: The wix page is doing this programmatically using data attributes.  The best way to accurately replicate this would be to use JS to get the width of the dropdown, subtract the width of the nav link, divide the result by 2 and move the dropdown left by that many pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use absolute properties in this case. Though in case of responsive design you have to tweak your code accordingly. As you question is regarding the desktop screen design, here is the way to solve it. I have added classes to the respective dropdown parent classes and added these properties:

```
.dropdown__search-mls {
 left: -20%;
}
.dropdown__area-info {
  left: -60%;
}
```

You can refer this fiddle: [Fiddle link to the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/hLnfy9r0/5/)